# Serving files and assets from a subdirectory

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I'm attempting to server files and assets from a subdirectory of a site, like this:

Site: /go/tools/ (index.html is the root file)
With assets linked like this: /go/tools/assets/js/main.js

using nginx, my configuration looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name local.tools;

    index index.html;

    location /go/tools {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            root /code/testing/build;
            try_files $uri /$uri /index.html =404;
    }
```

When I load the site with the url local.tools/go/tools, the index.html page loads and the html looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="icon" href="assets/img/favicon.ico">
    <link href="assets/css/vendor/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="assets/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>...
```

So that part is good. The problem is that the style and javascript aren't there. When I view the network tab, I see each asset is loading the index.html content instead of its own content.

what am I missing in my configuration so if I go to: /go/tools/assets/css/styles.css that I see the actual stylesheet?

Comment: First of all `/$uri` should be `$uri/`. When you generated the assets or build did you specify the base href as `/go/tools` ? Also how are you building the assets. Currently your requests would be going to `http://domain/assets/css/vendor/bootstrap.css` and giving 404 in browser?

Comment: I just changed /$uri to $uri/ and got the exact same result. The assets are located in `/code/testing/build/assets`, while the root of the site is in `/code/testing/build`, so nothing too spectacular there.

Comment: Can you confirm my 404 question?

Comment: In the source, the assets look like this: `<domain>/go/tools/assets/css/vendor/bootstrap.css`. I'm not getting a 404 - I'm just getting the contents of index.html in each of the assets.

Comment: Add a `location /go/tools/assets/ {}` inside the existing location block and that should fix the issue then. I am assuming `/code/testing/build/go/tools/assets/css/vendor/bootstrap.css` this file exists

Comment: it would be located on /code/testing/build/assets/css/vendor/bootstrap.css

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155634/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-francis-lewis).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use below config

```
location /go/tools {
        location /go/tools/assets/ {
            alias /code/testing/build/assets/;
        }
        alias /code/testing/build;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
}
```

Basically when url is `/go/tools/assets` you need the search to happen from `/assets` in the build directory. That is why we need alias in the nested location

Comment: Now my assets are showing correctly, but I'm getting an endless redirect loop when I load the `/go/tools/index.html`